# What is the correct practice for updating a .net WCF service from SQL Server when data changes via replication

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, sqldependency

Environment: 
Replicated Server: SQL Server 2008 R2
Client Server: SQL Server Express
Language: .Net 3.5 C#

The replicated server will be continually updated by web services and have many of the tables published.

The Client Server will have a down stream subscription to the replicated server.

Goal:
As the SQL Express instance pulls its subscription updates it will need to notify a WCF service so as to pass updates to the client front end.

Is this something best suited to SQLDependency or perhaps using CLR triggers to contact WCF? Is there a good practice for dealing with this type of flow without the use of polling?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that SQLDependency does not scale well.  You mention that web services update the database, I would recommend that these web services use WCF to talk directly to the Client Server.

Comment: The client server and its services / front end have to all be decoupled from the main system. This is why it is using a replication subscription as an update mechanism. The through put of the main system is not very high.. likely no more than a few dozen transactions a minute at its peak.